# Tomcat WAR cannot lookup to EJB

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

I have an application that were packaged in one `EAR`. The `EAR` has two module:

- backend.jar (it includes my `entity classes` and my `session beans`) as BackEnd
- frontend.war (it includes my `managed beans` and my `jsf pages`) as FrontEnd

Basicly I was deploying this application to a `Weblogic 12c` server (i mean booth module at same server packaged into one EAR) I didn't use `CDI` to look up my `EJB`-s. I have a class  in my FrontEnd  which looks up remote interface of my `EJB-s` in the backend:

This is how my look up class looks like:

```
 public class RequestHandlerFrontHelper {


    private RequestHandlerEJBRemote requestHandlerEJB;

    final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FragmentHandlerMB.class);


    public RequestHandlerEJBRemote getRequestHandlerEJB() {
        return requestHandlerEJB;
    }


    public RequestHandlerFrontHelper() {
        super();
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(EnvironmentHandler.getInstance().showLogProp());

        try {
            Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            env.put(PropertyHandler.getPropertyByName("naming_init_key"),
                    PropertyHandler.getPropertyByName("naming_init_val"));
            env.put(PropertyHandler.getPropertyByName("naming_prov_url_key"),
                    PropertyHandler.getPropertyByName("naming_prov_url_val"));
            env.put(PropertyHandler.getPropertyByName("naming_sec_key"),
                    PropertyHandler.getPropertyByName("naming_sec_val"));
            env.put(PropertyHandler.getPropertyByName("naming_sec_cred_key"),
                    PropertyHandler.getPropertyByName("naming_sec_cred_val"));

            log.info("env: " + env);

            Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
            requestHandlerEJB = (RequestHandlerEJBRemote) ctx
                    .lookup("RequestHandlerEJB#com.kebodev.session.RequestHandlerEJBRemote");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

While my whole application where depleyed to `Weblogic 12c` there wasn't any problem i could access my `remote EJB`.

Now i have to separate the backend and the frontend of the application and I try to deploy the frontend to `Tomcat 8.0` server and deploy my backend to `Weblogic 12c`

My frontend module starts to run on `Tomcat`, and my backend module starts to run on `Weblogic` as well. But when I try to invoke my remote EJB from the frontend I got this exception:

```
RequestHandlerFrontHelper:46 - env: {java.naming.provider.url=t3://127.0.0.1:7001, java.naming.factory.initial =weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory, java.naming.security.principal=weblogic, java.naming.security.credentials=SolarDhom1985}
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [RequestHandlerEJB#com.kebodev.session.RequestHandlerEJBRemote] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [RequestHandlerEJB#com.kebodev.session.RequestHandlerEJBRemote].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:157)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at com.kebodev.request.RequestHandlerFrontHelper.<init>(RequestHandlerFrontHelper.java:50)
    at com.kebodev.managed.LoginHandlerMB.autAD(LoginHandlerMB.java:106)
    at com.kebodev.managed.LoginHandlerMB.validate(LoginHandlerMB.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:245)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.kebodev.filters.LoginWebFilter.doFilter(LoginWebFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.kebodev.filters.CharFilter.doFilter(CharFilter.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is how my Weblogic RMI properties looks like:

```
naming_init_key=java.naming.factory.initial 
naming_init_val=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
naming_prov_url_key=java.naming.provider.url
naming_prov_url_val=t3://127.0.0.1:7001
naming_sec_key=java.naming.security.principal
naming_sec_val=weblogic
naming_sec_cred_key=java.naming.security.credentials
naming_sec_cred_val=pass
legal_min_prob=60
faktor_max_prob=20
```

My `backend.jar` included in my `frontend.war` also.

I would like to ask what is the proper way to deploy the frontend and the backend separately to different servers. I would like to do this due to security reasons because we will have a separate domains for backend tasks and for frontend tasks.

**UPDATE:**

I added this two file to my Tomcat lib folder: wlclient.jar wlthint3client.jar and change the look up class:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "weblogic");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pass");

log.info("env: " + env);

Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

 //weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessObject obj =(weblogic.ejb.spi.BusinessObject) ctx.lookup("RequestHandlerEJB#com.kebodev.session.RequestHandlerEJBRemote");  
 //requestHandlerEJB = (RequestHandlerEJBRemote) obj._WL_getBusinessObjectHandle().getBusinessObject();

requestHandlerEJB = (RequestHandlerEJBRemote) ctx.lookup("RequestHandlerEJB#com.kebodev.session.RequestHandlerEJBRemote");
```

Now it's not throwing `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException` and my `requestHandlerEJB` class is `com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62` but if i try to invoke any method on this object I get `NullPointerException`

Comment: `t3://127.0.0.1:7001` isn't going to work on tomcat. `t3` is a weblogic protocol, and 127.0.0.1 is localhost. So you're telling tomcat to connect to weblogic on tomcat. That isn't right.

Comment: now i have weblogic and tomcat on the same machine. So i telling my frontend to connect weblogic t3 protocol. My weblogic running on 127.0.0.1:7001 and my tomcat running on 127.0.0.1:8080 i think its not the problem.

Comment: **Why** would you run tomcat and weblogic on one server?

Comment: I'm just trying to make it run now. Of course later Tomcat and Weblogic wouldn't be at the same server.